# ASP.NET MVC Foreach from multiple dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm trying to get a value from each dropdownlist in the view model. I'm doing with a foreach but that doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help me here please?

I'm doing in the controller the foreach. I'm using Entity Framework and repository methods to this. Any help is helpful.

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(int? id, AddSaidasServicoViewModel model, string command)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //TODO: adicionar Userhelper para ver quem cria a saida. Criar campo na tabela BD.  Ver apontamento Notepad
            if (command.Equals("submit1"))
            {
                await _saidaservicoRepository.AddSaidaServicoAsync(model);
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Create));
            }
            else
            {
                foreach(var elementoId in model.Elementos )
                {
                    await _elementoRepository.UpdateElementoSaidaServicosAsync(model);
                }
            }

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        
        return View(model);
}
```

View markup:

```
@model FireHouseGest.web.Models.AddSaidasServicoViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h2>Criar</h2>

<h4>Saída Serviço</h4>
<hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <form asp-action="Create">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    
    
                <div class="container">
    
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label asp-for="ServicoId" class="control-label"></label>
                                    <select asp-for="ServicoId" asp-items="Model.Servicos" class="form-control"></select>
                                    <span asp-validation-for="ServicoId" class="text-danger"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label asp-for="ViaturaId" class="control-label"></label>
                                    <select asp-for="ViaturaId" asp-items="Model.Viaturas" class="form-control"></select>
                                    <span asp-validation-for="ViaturaId" class="text-danger"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
    
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" name="command" value="submit1" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-2 text-center">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label asp-for="ElementoId" class="control-label"></label>
                                <select asp-for="ElementoId" asp-items="Model.Elementos" class="form-control"></select>
                                <span asp-validation-for="ElementoId" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2 text-center">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label asp-for="ElementoId" class="control-label"></label>
                                <select asp-for="ElementoId" asp-items="Model.Elementos" class="form-control"></select>
                                <span asp-validation-for="ElementoId" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2 text-center">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label asp-for="ElementoId" class="control-label"></label>
                                <select asp-for="ElementoId" asp-items="Model.Elementos" class="form-control"></select>
                                <span asp-validation-for="ElementoId" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2 text-center">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label asp-for="ElementoId" class="control-label"></label>
                                <select asp-for="ElementoId" asp-items="Model.Elementos" class="form-control"></select>
                                <span asp-validation-for="ElementoId" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2 text-center">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label asp-for="ElementoId" class="control-label"></label>
                                <select asp-for="ElementoId" asp-items="Model.Elementos" class="form-control"></select>
                                <span asp-validation-for="ElementoId" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" name="command" value="submit2" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>          
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Adecorrer" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Adecorrer" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Adecorrer" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Inicio" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Inicio" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Inicio" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Fim" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Fim" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Fim" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
    
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

ViewModel

```
    namespace FireHouseGest.web.Models
{
    public class AddSaidasServicoViewModel
    {


        public int SaidaServicoId { get; set; }


        
        [Display(Name = "Elementos")]
        public int ElementoId { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Elementos { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "Viatura")]
        public int ViaturaId { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Viaturas { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "Serviço")]
        public int ServicoId { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Servicos { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "Estado")]
        public int Adecorrer { get; set; }


        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm }", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
        public DateTime Inicio { get { return DateTime.Now; } }


        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm }", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
        public DateTime? Fim { get; set; }


        public User user { get; set; }

        
    }
}
```

This is what I have. Open to suggestions.

Comment: Missing the view model but based on the view 1) it does not contain the `Elementos` property (well, it has, but POST is returning `ElementoId`), 2) why iterating over `model.Elementos` but passing a `model` to `UpdateElementoSaidaServicosAsync`, 3) does Your view contains the @model definition and You just didn't copy it?

Comment: Just added the modelview.

Answer (score 0):

Before coding, you need know the following things:

1.Model Binding find and bind the property by matching the `name` of the input.

2.If you have multiple inputs with the same name, you need set a `List<T>` type parameter to receive all the values.

3.Dropdownlist gets the selected option **value**(*not text*),be sure the type of the value is the same with the type of matched property.  (**e.g.** `ElementoId` is int type,so the value of each SelectListItem in `Elementos` should be int or it could be converted to int):

```
var model = new AddSaidasServicoViewModel()
{
    Elementos = new List<SelectListItem>() {
                new SelectListItem() { Value = "1", Text = "Elementos1" },
                new SelectListItem() { Value = "2", Text = "Elementos2" },
                new SelectListItem() { Value = "3", Text = "Elementos3" }
                },
      //....
};
```

4.Dropdownlist selected value will match the property by searching the same name of the `asp-for="xxx"`. (**e.g.** `asp-for="ElementoId"` will generate html:`id="ElementoId" name="ElementoId"`,so this input value will match the property ElementoId in your model)

5.Although you have two submit button, but the submit button will always submit **all the input values** which they are in **the same form**.

Change your code like below and you will receive all the selected ElementoId values in `List<string> ElementoId`:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(int? id, AddSaidasServicoViewModel model,
                                                    List<string> ElementoId, string command)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //TODO: adicionar Userhelper para ver quem cria a saida. Criar campo na tabela BD.  Ver apontamento Notepad
        if (command.Equals("submit1"))
        {
            //...
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var elementoId in ElementoId)
            {
                //....
            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Rena for answer. this was what i did.

```
public async Task UpdateElementosSaidasAsync(AddSaidasServicoViewModel model, List<string> Elementos)
    {
        int SaidaServicos = _context.SaidaServicos.Max(item => item.Id);
        var Saida = await _context.SaidaServicos.FindAsync(SaidaServicos);



        if (Elementos == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        else
        {
            foreach (var elementoId in Elementos)
            {

                var updateElementoSaida = _context.Elementos.Where(e => e.Id == Convert.ToInt32(elementoId)).FirstOrDefault();
                updateElementoSaida.saidaServico = Saida;
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            }

        }

        return;
    }
```